# Bootstrap grid for phone and pcs

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new to responsive HTML and bootstrap, I am trying to wrap my head around bootstrap grid.

I need a row with 1 col visible on any device higher than phones (xs) and another column always shows for all devices.

Can anyone please help?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any code to go off as an example.. The [Bootstrap Website](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes) provides a nice table which outlines what classes will be visible for each screen resolution. You should be able to use these classes in combination to achieve the result you are describing.

For example:

```
<div class="col-md-6 hidden-xs">
 I will not be visible on mobiles.
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
 I will be visible on all devices.
</div>
```